# Get table's value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a table and i need to get some value of that table.I tried it but can't

In here I want to get the 7700-5-3300-4455 Value.(In first input field)

### My Table HTML

```
 <table id="inUti">
 <tbody><tr></tr><tr class="x1">
 <td><input id="nid45global" disabled="" class="form-control" value="7700-5-3300-4455" type="text"></td>
 <td><input id="nid55local" class="form-control" value="1/2" type="text"></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody></table>
```

I tried it like this.

```
   var newsLocator = $("#inUti").closest('tr').children('tr').children('td:first').text(); // Thisone returns Empty
```

Comment: If you have an id why don't get directly the val of this element ? `$('#nid45global').val()`

Comment: What about `$("#nid45global").val()`.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest option is to pick them using therir ID

```
$("#nid45global").val();
```

If you want to be specific with that table,

```
$("#inUti").find('.x1 td input#nid45global').val();
```

Or

```
$("#inUti .x1").find("td:first-child input").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just say $("#inUti input").val();
Just another way!

Answer (score -1):

try this one to get value dynamically

```
$(#inUti").find(".x > td:nth-child(1) > input").val();
```

This will give the actual result as per your requirement